# Laravel Eloquent whereHas error unknown column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get the **lowest price of a product to an item**.

```
$items=Item::whereHas('products', function($query){
        $query->orderBy('price','asc')->first();
    })->with('page')->get();
```

Model **Item.php**

```
public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product','item_id','id');
}
```

**ERROR**

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'items.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`item_id` = `items`.`id` order by `price` asc limit 1)

Comment: Please run the query that you got in error in phpmyadmin and check if it gives the error ? If so, check your laravel query

Comment: I think the query gives error because it is missing "from products,items"

Comment: Yes you were missing that as well

Comment: Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: You can use DB::select(DB::raw('your-query')) to execute and get a collection

Comment: I wil try that, Is that a good solution though? It is a pretty simple query.. Thanks

Comment: It is a fairely good solution. Also, check if your 'items' table has 'id' column

Comment: Please check if you have a `items` table and that it has an `id` field

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
DB::select(DB::raw("select * from products where products.item_id = items.id order by price asc limit 1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked up Laravel Eloquent documentation and changed code a little bit and now it works.

```
    $items=Item::with(['products' => function($query){
        $query->orderBy('price','asc')->first();
    },'page'])->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships